# HTML: Nesting DIVs problem

Tags: html

I am coding a form generator. So far, so good, then I decided to give it a real test.

I made a form with some nested  each holding a few controls.

I will post the HTML at the end. If you load it into a browser, it renders, but is obviously wrong.

I had previously tested using the W3C validator and things were fine, but that was for non nested. When I validate a form with nested  I get errors:

```
Error  Line 13, Column 117: document type does not allow element "DIV" here

…style="position: absolute; top:88px; left: 256px; width: 145px; height: 21px;">
```

So, how do I correct that? What do I do with nested FIELDSETs?

Here's the complete HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="C:\temp\an_elogger_test.php" method="get"><div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:24px; left:24px; width: 449px; height: 473px;">
<legend>GroupBox1</legend>
<div class="TPanel" id="Panel1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:64px; left:64px; width: 361px; height: 217px;">
<legend></legend>
<div class="TComboBox" id="ComboBox1" style="position: absolute; top:88px; left: 256px; width: 145px; height: 21px;">
  <select name="ComboBox1">
    <option value="- one -" selected="selected">- one -</option>
    <option value="- two -">- two -</option>
    <option value="- three -">- three -</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox2">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:80px; left:88px; width: 145px; height: 177px;">
<legend>GroupBox2</legend>
<div class="TCheckBox" id="CheckBox1" style="position: absolute; top:112px; left: 104px; width: 97px; height: 17px;">CheckBox1<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" value="CheckBox1Checked"></div>
<div class="TCheckBox" id="CheckBox2" style="position: absolute; top:152px; left: 112px; width: 97px; height: 17px;">CheckBox2<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox2" value="CheckBox2Checked"checked="checked"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="TRadioGroup" id="RadioGroup2">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:128px; left: 264px; width: 145px; height: 137px;"><legend>RadioGroup2</legend>

eins: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="eins" checked><br>

zwei: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="zwei"><br>

drei: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="drei"><br>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="TMemo" id="Memo1"><textarea name="Memo1" rows="8" cols="13" style="position: absolute; top:320px; left: 88px; width: 185px; height: 89px;">
</textarea>
</div>
<div class="TComboBox" id="ComboBox2" style="position: absolute; top:328px; left: 296px; width: 145px; height: 21px;">
  <select name="ComboBox2">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d" selected="selected">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="TPanel" id="Panel2">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:32px; left:520px; width: 425px; height: 449px;">
<legend></legend>
<div class="TPanel" id="Panel3">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:64px; left:552px; width: 345px; height: 185px;">
<legend></legend>
<div class="TMemo" id="Memo2"><textarea name="Memo2" rows="8" cols="13" style="position: absolute; top:88px; left: 584px; width: 185px; height: 89px;">
You may wish to leave this memo emptyOr perpahaps give instructions aboout what should be written here</textarea>
</div>
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; top:200px; left: 600px; width: 121px; height: 21px;"><input type="text" name="Edit1"value="Insert text here"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox3">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:272px; left:552px; width: 345px; height: 185px;">
<legend>GroupBox3</legend>
<div class="TPanel" id="Panel4">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:304px; left:584px; width: 177px; height: 137px;">
<legend></legend>
<div class="TRadioGroup" id="RadioGroup1">
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top:312px; left: 600px; width: 97px; height: 105px;"><legend>RadioGroup1</legend>

one: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="one"><br>

two: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="two" checked><br>

three: <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="three"><br>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit2" style="position: absolute; top:320px; left: 776px; width: 105px; height: 21px;"><input type="text" name="Edit2"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a `<legend>something</legend>` element before the div inside the fieldset.

Fieldsets are block level elements, but you have to have a legend inside it for compliance.

Comment: It's stated at http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.10 that the `<legend></legend>` must always come as the first tag before anything else in the `fieldset`.

Comment: That solved the validation problem, but the layout is still screwy. I will edit the question and update the new HTML

Comment: I will award an answer for this (wish I could award two) and look into the layout problem. If necessary I will as a new question.  I did update the HTML above, though.